# The proportion of heads after many coin tosses

Tags: probability

Probability works not by compensating for imbalances, but by overwhelming them. Suppose that the first 10 tosses of a coin give 10 tails and that tosses after that are exactly half heads and half tails. (Exact balance is unlikely, but the example illustrates how the first 10 outcomes are swapped by later outcomes).

1) What is the proportion of heads after the first 10 tosses?

2) What is the proportion of heads after 100 tosses if half of the last 90 produces heads (45 heads)?

3) What is the proportion of heads after 1000 tosses if half of the last 990 produce heads

4) What is the proportion of heads after 10000 tosses if half of the last 9990 produce heads?

My solution: all answers are 1/2. But my answer is wrong and I don't know why. I thought the proportion of tossing a coin should be 1/2 in any situation because it must be 2 possible, head or tail. Can anyone please help me figure it out? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proportion of heads after the first ten tosses is zero because the first ten are all tails. The proportion of heads after the first hundred tosses is
$$
{45\over100}=0.45
$$
Similarly for 3 and 4, you get $0.495$ and $0.4995$.

The question is asking you to calculate the numbers rather than say what the probability of heads or tails is.

Comment: The given relative frequencies correspond to 49 heads in 100 tosses which is 1 away from
50 (half of 100), then 493 in 1000 which is 7 away from 500 then 4969 in 10000 which is
31 away from 5000 and finally 49,926 in 100,000 which is 74 away from 50,000. 


This is the answer that our teacher gave us. Is it same as what were you trying to say? I am still not sure.

Comment: @Momoko In your question you said that the first ten tosses were all tails. If there are 45 heads and 45 tails in the subsequent tosses, that would mean 55 tails and 45 heads. So I do not understand what "the given relative frequencies correspond to 49 heads in 100 tosses" means. Possibly there is an error in your question.

Answer (score 1):

i)I think this means the proportion of heads after the first 10 tosses *but* including the first 10 tosses. So, say , to simplify, the first toss after the 10 , i.e., the 11th toss, and every other toss is a head. Then lets examine the proportion.

11th toss: proportion of heads = 1/11 , since first 10 were all tails, 11th toss was heads.

12th toss is a tails, by assumption. Proportion of heads is $\frac{1}{12}$ .

13th toss: we get heads, proportion is $\frac {2}{13}$.

............

..........

2n-1 th) toss proportion is $\frac {2n-1 -10}{2n-1}= \frac {2n-11}{2n-1}$

2n th) toss proportion is $\frac {2n -10}{2n} $.

Notice that as $n$ grows, the proportion approaches